# When retyping in the searchbar is not working

Tags: javascript, search

I created a search box, when the user search on it will focus on what the user search. If I search **About** it will focus on the title “About”, then I scroll to bottom or up and search again **About** it didn’t focus on anything.

```js
function Focus() {
  var search = document.getElementById("search-box").value;

  if (search.toLowerCase() == "about") {
    window.location.hash = '#about';
    document.getElementById("search-box").value = "";

    console.log("about")
  } else if (search.toLowerCase() == "skills") {
    window.location.hash = '#skill';
    document.getElementById("search-box").value = "";

    console.log("skills")
  } else if (search == "") {
    alert("Search Field is empty. Type anything");
  } else {
    alert("Not Found");
    document.getElementById("search-box").value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="search-box" placeholder="Search">
<button type="submit" id="searchbar" onclick="Focus()">Search</button>



<h1 id="about">About</h1>

<h1 id="skill">Skills</h1>

<!-- There are so many things under this titles. -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Balaji Sivasakthi already answered, I would like to point out that you repeat a lot of code.

1. If you want to clear the search box, you don't need to write that in every single if statement. You only need to write it once *outside* the if statement.
2. If you save `search` as a variable, you can use that variable for `getElementById`.
3. Save that element as a variable as well (`element` below), and you can check if it exists.
4. Declare a `message` variable, and put an alert outside of the if statements. If message has any value apart from "", trigger the alert.

```js
function Focus() {
  var searchBox = document.getElementById("search-box")
  var search = searchBox.value.toLowerCase();  // 2
  var element = document.getElementById(search); // 2 & 3
  var message = "";  // 4

  window.location.hash = '#';

  if (element) {  // 3 -- checks if you found any elements with id #{search}
    window.location.hash += search;  // adds element id to hash
    console.log({search});
  } else if (search) {  // 2 & 4 -- anything else than "" is true
    message = "Not Found";
  } else {
    message = "Search Field is empty. Type anything"
  }
  
  searchBox.value = ""; // 1
  
  if (message) { alert(message) } // 4 -- anything else than "" is true
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="search-box" placeholder="Search">
<button type="submit" id="searchbar" onclick="Focus()">Search</button>



<h1 id="about">About</h1>

<h1 id="skills">Skills</h1>

<!-- There are so many things under this titles. -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear the hash before assign new hash. `window.location.hash = '';`

```
if (search.toLowerCase() == "about") {
    window.location.hash = '';
    window.location.hash = '#about';
    document.getElementById("search-box").value = "";
    }
else if(search.toLowerCase() == "skills") {
    window.location.hash = '';
    window.location.hash = '#skill';
    document.getElementById("search-box").value = "";
    }
else if(search==""){
    alert("Search Field is empty. Type anything");
}
else{
    alert("Not Found");
    document.getElementById("search-box").value = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the hash (#about) don't change when you search for the same hash twice. The browser will only scroll if the hash changes.

I think the best way is search for the element when you klick on the search button and get the offset of the element and then scroll to that position:

Get the Offset of the element:

```
element.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

Scroll to Position

```
window.scroll(x, y)
```

Comment: It's  [`window.scrollTo(x,y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) or `window.scrollLeft = x; window.scrollTop = y;`.

Comment: it dosn't matter.

`window.scroll` and `window.scrollTo` are the same. see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll